# Limit of a function involving cdf and pdf of a normal variable

Tags: limits, proof-writing, limits-without-lhopital

I want to find the limits in $\infty, $ and $-\infty$ of the function $f(z)= (z\Phi + \phi )(2\Phi^2-2\Phi+1)-z\Phi^2$ where $\phi=\phi(z)$ is the pdf of a standard normal variable, and $\Phi=\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of a standard normal variable. I know this limits are zero in both cases, but I want to prove it formally.

This is what I have done, for the case in which $z \rightarrow \infty$,

$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} f(z)= \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} 2z\Phi^3-2z\Phi^2+z\Phi+2\phi\Phi^2-2\phi \Phi+\phi-z\Phi^2$

which is equal to
$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} 2z\Phi^3-3z\Phi^2+z\Phi + \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} 2\phi \Phi^2-2\phi \Phi+\phi=\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}2z\Phi^3-3z\Phi^2+z\Phi+0$

This limit

$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} 2z\Phi^3-3z\Phi^2+z\Phi=\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} z (2\Phi^3-3\Phi^2+\Phi)$ is of the form $\infty \times 0$ so I have tried to write the expression as:

$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} z/({\frac{1}{(2\Phi^3-3\Phi^2+\Phi)}})$ and use Hopital rule, but I am getting things of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ since the derivatives of $\Phi$ have the term $\phi$ and this is zero in the limit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use an easy estimate, with

$$\phi(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}
\qquad \Phi(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^z e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} d t$$

When $t \ge 1$ one has $e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\le t e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$, hence
$$
z\ge 1 \Longrightarrow
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} d t
\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^{+\infty} t e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} d t
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} = \phi(z)
$$
It follows that
$$z\ge 1 \Longrightarrow 0\le (1-\Phi(z))\le \phi(z)$$
Now since $\lim_\limits{z\to+\infty}z^k\phi(z) = 0$ for any $k\in {\mathbb R}$, we have
$\lim_\limits{z\to+\infty}z^k (1-\Phi(z)) = 0$

When $z\to - \infty$, we know that $\Phi(z)= (1 - \Phi(-z))$, hence
$\lim_\limits{z\to-\infty}|z|^k \Phi(z) = 0$.

Now observe that $2\Phi^3 - 3 \Phi^2+ \Phi = \Phi(1 -\Phi)(1 - 2\Phi)$.
It follows easily that $|z|^k (2\Phi^3 - 3 \Phi^2+ \Phi)\to 0$ when $z\to \pm\infty$.